# Scrapy does not click through all pages

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl through a webshop. The products are dynamically loaded, which is why I'm using Selenium to crawl through the pages. I am starting out to scrape all the categories, which are then called for the main function.

The problem occurs while crawling through each category: The spider is instructed to scrape all the data from the first page and then click on a button to get to the next page until there is no button left. The code works fine if I'm just putting in one category url as `start_url`, but strangely enough, if I run it in my main code, it does not click through all the pages. It randomly switches to a new category before finishing clicking on all the next-buttons.

And I don't have any idea on why this is the case.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from horni.items import HorniItem

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class horniSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "final"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for post in response.xpath('//body'):
            item = HorniItem()
            for href in response.xpath('//li[@class="sub"]/a/@href'):
                item['maincategory'] = response.urljoin(href.extract())
                yield scrapy.Request(item['maincategory'], callback = self.parse_subcategories)

    def parse_subcategories(self, response):
        item = HorniItem()
        for href in response.xpath('//li[@class="sub"]/a/@href'):
            item['subcategory'] = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(item['subcategory'], callback = self.parse_articles)


    def __init__(self):
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
            self.driver.close()

    def parse_articles(self, response):
            self.driver.get(response.url)
            response = TextResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
            item = HorniItem()
            for sel in response.xpath('//body'):
                item['title'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="article-list-headline"]/div/h1/text()').extract()
                yield item
            for post in response.xpath('//body'):
            id = post.xpath('//a[@class="title-link"]/@href').extract()
            prices = post.xpath('///span[@class="price ng-binding"]/text()').extract()
                articles = post.xpath('//a[@class="title-link"]/span[normalize-space()]/text()').extract()
                id = [i.split('/')[-2] for i in id]
            prices = [x for x in prices if x != u'\xa0']
                articles = [w.replace(u'\n', '') for w in articles]
                result = zip(id, prices, articles)
                for id, price, article in result:
                        item = HorniItem()
                        item['id'] = id
                item['price'] = price
                        item['name'] = article
                        yield item
            while True:
                next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="paging-wrapper"]/a[@class="paging-btn right"]')
                try:
                        next.click()
                    response = TextResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
                item = HorniItem()
                    for post in response.xpath('//body'):
                    id = post.xpath('//a[@class="title-link"]/@href').extract()
                    prices = post.xpath('///span[@class="price ng-binding"]/text()').extract()
                        articles = post.xpath('//a[@class="title-link"]/span[normalize-space()]/text()').extract()
                        id = [i.split('/')[-2] for i in id]
                    prices = [x for x in prices if x != u'\xa0']
                        articles = [w.replace(u'\n', '') for w in articles]
                        result = zip(id, prices, articles)
                        for id, price, article in result:
                            item = HorniItem()
                                item['id'] = id
                        item['price'] = price
                                item['name'] = article
                                yield item
                except:
                        break
```

## Update

So it seems that the problem lies with the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`-setting. As the next-button on the website does in fact not generate a new url but simply execute a Java-Script, the site URL does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer:

The problem was that since the content of the page was dynamically generated, clicking the `NEXT`-button did not actually change the url. In conjunction with the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`-setting of the project, this meant that the spider stayed on the page for a given amount of time, regardless of if it was able to click every possible `NEXT`-button.

Setting the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`-setting  high enough allowed the spider to stay long enough on each url and crawl every page.

The problem is however that this forces the spider to wait the set time on *every* url, even if there is no `NEXT`-button to click. But well...